# Which metal does the most damage when crafted into a weapon?

Tags: gnomoria

What is the order here? Which metals are best for weapon and armor crafting? What is the progressing in that sense? I would suspect Steel to be more effective than Silver, but real life logic does not apply always to video games.

Answer (score 2):

Right now Steel provides the best stats at a 5.2 damage multiplier according to [this](http://www.gnomoriawiki.com/wiki/Weapons_and_Armor#Metal_Effects_on_Weapons_and_Armor). It actually does seem to follow real logic seeing as Gold, Silver, PLatinum and Rose Gold are virtually useless.

At the moment, the kind of metal does not affect the stats of tools like Pickaxe's and Felling Axe's though.

Comment: Do you actually play the game or just looked up the wiki?

Comment: I do play the game. I just play on peaceful mode. I wouldn't have answered if the wiki didn't include this though since I have no experience with combat. I was actually surprised that metal affects combat at all since it still doesn't affect tools.